# Неверный путь к файлу LOAD_FILE

Tags: sql, mysql

привет.
Как узнать правильный путь к файлу при загрузке файла в БД?

```
$sql1="SELECT LOAD_FILE('R:\home\localhost\www\some.txt')";//-дает NULL
$sql1="SELECT LOAD_FILE('some.txt')";//-NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Путь к файлу должен быть абсолютным и файл должен быть в "полной доступности" (проверьте права на файл).

```
$sql1="SELECT LOAD_FILE('R:\\home\localhost\www\some.txt')";
```